# php date convert to javascript date

Tags: php, javascript

I have a php date and wish to echo it out in a javascript alert box:-

```
$day=15;
$month=8;
$year=2012;

$date_display = date("Y-m-d", mktime(0, 0, 0, $month, $day, $year));
echo $date_display; // 2012-08-15
```

Then,

```
<a href="#" onclick="give_date(<?=$date_display;?>)"><?=$day;?></a>
```

The javascript function:

```
<script>
function give_date(value){
alert (value);  
}
</script>
```

Interestingly, the alert box give me "1989", which equals to 2012 minus 8 minus 15!! what shall I do!!

Comment: Since you use `date` it shouldn't make much difference, but in general, you're making a mistake here by confusing between the client-side and the server-side. The value of `$date_display` is calculated on the server-side while `onclick` is called on the client side. As for your problem, try casting to `String`.

Comment: @alfasin: nope, it's not true

Comment: @alfasin: the thing that "The value of $date_display is calculated on the server-side". This thing would confuse OP even more, since it's not clear what "calculated" here means: either initialization with `'2012-08-15'` string value or math evaluation. And second - "As for your problem, try casting to String" --- to cast to string *what*? In php it is a string - makes no sense, in js - it's too late, so makes no sense as well

Comment: @zerkms when I said "cast to string" I meant adding quotes - my bad. But, All the first part of my comment is valid. Many programmers confuse server-side with client-side. The date is calculated on the server-side, so if the server is in US and the customer is in Europe, the browser might show that date of yesterday (from the client perspective). Confusing ? too bad, programming isn't always easy :)

Comment: By the way, it is better to use `<?php echo $date_display; ?>` rather than `<?=$date_display;?>`. And don't use `mktime`, use [`time`](http://nz.php.net/manual/en/function.time.php).

Comment: @Shaquin Trifonoff: and how to use `time()` in this case?

Comment: @zerkms and whoever else read my comment: Sorry, I got mixed up about `mktime` and `time`. `time` is just for the current time, and `mktime` is for converting a date into milliseconds :-)

Comment: @Shaquin Trifonoff: "and mktime is for converting a date into milliseconds" --- nope. mktime is for creating unix timestamp from date parts

Comment: @zerkms - Never mind about the details. *Seconds* then. That is basically what a UNIX timestamp is (seconds since 1970).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now you get: `<a href="#" onclick="give_date(2012-08-15)">15</a>`, so it calculates it in browser.

the solution is simple - add quotes:

```
<a href="#" onclick="give_date('<?=$date_display;?>')"><?=$day;?></a>
```

Then you get: `<a href="#" onclick="give_date('2012-08-15')">15</a>`

Answer (score 1):

You are making the *client-side code* show an `alert` with the date of the *server* when the page was loaded.

If you want to show the user the current time, use this:

**HTML:**

```
<a href="#" id="date">Please enable JavaScript.</a>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function show_date() {
    alert(new Date());  
}
window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById('date').innerHTML = new Date().getDay();
};
document.getElementById('date').onclick = show_date;
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery if you are up for it

```
<a href="#" id="<?php echo $date_display; ?>">Click to get date popup</a>

$(function(){

 $('a').click(function(){

       var dt = $(this).attr('id');
       alert(dt);
 });

});
```

Comment: `2012-08-05` is not a good candidate to be used as an `id`. I'd suggest to use `data-date="..."` instead

Comment: @zerkms A little curious here, why not?

Comment: Hmm...but it serves what the OP wants right? I guess it can be overlooked

Comment: `id` should begin with letter. It's how standard defines requirement to `id`. You may do whatever you want, but the standard is a standard. And it is a good idea to follow it